# Rebuilding of the Indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, indexing

Index rebuilding is taking too much time. what could be the possible factors affecting the rebuilding of indexes. usually when i do the rebuilding it doesn't take more than a min.

Syntax :

```
ALTER INDEX Pk_customer ON Customer REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR=90, SORT_IN_TEMPDB =    ON,STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF) Go
```

Table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customer](
[pkey] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[cid] [char](15) 
[name] [char](100) 
[cust_group] [char](20) 
[language] [char](2) 
[start] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[stop] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[country] [char](2) 
[_INSERTED] [datetime] NULL 
[_INSERTEDBY] [varchar](max) 
[_UPDATED] [datetime] NULL,
[_UPDATEDBY] [char](20) 
CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[pkey] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [FG_BASE]) ON [FG_BASE]
```

Comment: How many records are there in the table?  What's the fragmentation?  Are records deleted from the table often?

Comment: This isnt enough information to go off of. Index rebuilding has a ton of factors. When you do it (how busy the server is), the fragmentation of the indexs, the usage of the indexs, the data present. We need more info to help

Comment: There are just 1000 record and no insertion or deletion is done recently on this table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said:

> what could be the possible factors affecting the rebuilding of indexes. usually when i do the rebuilding it doesn't take more than a min.

So here are possible factors, unless you specify details we can't say for sure:

- Server utilization during the time of rebuild
- - Other jobs, backups, exports, reports, expensive queries and etc.
- Index fragmentation percentage at the time of rebuild
- Size of the table
- Overall server performance (CPU, RAM, Disk utilization) outside of SQL Server.

Comment: Hello, Please let me know what details you require which could help me in improving the performance.

Comment: 1. when you do it? Is it busy time or slow? 2. Quantify good and bad, what is actual time duration. 3. How often do you do it? Look at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858(v=sql.90).aspx for recommendations of items to check before rebuild.

Comment: It is a monthly process done every month's first week. The table is not used by any other process at the time when the re indexing is done.

Comment: Do you rebuild it after working hours or during work day? If you rebuild it during the day, you would want to change it to be at night. If level of fragmentation is very high, you need to consider changing job to by weekly or even weekly process. I would write the job to check fragmentation of all indexes on daily basis and to give you report which ones need to be rebuild, if you want to do it manually other wise just have job that runs every day and rebuilds all indexes every night that are above specific level.